# Using Hydra with JSON

Tags: hydra

Trying for the life of me to get Hydra to work with a JSON request.

**General:**

- Request URL: https://api.myapp.app/api/accounts/login/
- Request Method: POST
- Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
- Remote Address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers:**

- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST

**Request Headers:**

- Content-Type: application/json
- Origin: https://myapp.app
- Referer: https://myapp.app/login
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0

**Request Payload:**

```
{username: "root", password: "toor"}
password: "toor"
username: "root"
```

**Response for Invalid Login:**
{"error":"username or password incorrect"}

I have tried many iterations, but keep getting the following error message:
Receiving the following error message: [ERROR] Invalid target definition!

```
hydra https://api.myapp.app https-form-post "api/account/login:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F={\"error:\" \"username \" \"or \" \"password \" \"wrong\"}" -l root -p toor
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the Hydra command to work, but I did learn about patator, https://github.com/lanjelot/patator, which worked.

Patador command:

```
python patator.py http_fuzz url=https://api.myapp.app/api/login/ method=POST body='username=root&password=FILE0' 0=/home/[your dictionary file]
```

If anyone is a Hyrda expert, I am still interested in learning how to use Hydra for the same. While the patator tool works, I am not sure it supports rate limits and other features found in Hydra.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine `hydra` not working for the scenario you are trying to use it for. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/944303/unsure-if-i-have-understood-hydra-syntax-correctly) post speaks as to why you might be seeing the `Invalid target defintion` error.

Try adjusting the hydra command and removing the `http://` prepended to your API URL.

Full example:

```
hydra -l root -p toor api.myapp.app https-form-post "/api/accounts/login:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F={\"error:\" \"username \" \"or \" \"password \" \"wrong\"}"
```

The command can be further updated by replacing the `-p` flag with a `-P` for loading a password file.

Tested on hydra v8.6.

It is harder to further debug your issue as we cannot reproduce it, but this should address your immediate issue.